# colorbox error: Request unsuccessful: error

Tags: jquery, ajax, colorbox

I am trying to make colorbox work for my site. As for current, the box opens, but it won't open the image. Here is my code:

#### JavaScript

```
$('.group').colorbox();
```

#### HTML

```
<a style="margin-bottom: 3px;" href="http://www.url.de/produkte/image.php?f=&amp;d=1" class="group"><img border="0"  src="http://www.url.de/produkte/image.php?f=&amp;d=2" alt="" /></a>
```

The box opens but an error is displayed in place of the image. Should I open the image via an `iframe` instead?

Answer (score 2):

If the image is available this should work fine.

```
$('.group').colorbox({photo:true});
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/upQC5/1/

As you are using image.php you would need it to set to true.

[Documentation](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) -
photo   default- false
*If true, this setting forces ColorBox to display a link as a photo. Use this when automatic photo detection fails (such as using a url like 'photo.php' instead of 'photo.jpg')*

Comment: Yes it works. Can you explain to me, why it is neccessary to put "photo:true in it?

Answer (score 0):

In the colorbox [documentation](http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/), it says

> photo(setting)    false(default)  If true, this setting forces ColorBox to display a link as
>   a photo. Use this when automatic photo detection fails (such as using
>   a url like 'photo.php' instead of 'photo.jpg')

So, try

```
$('.group').colorbox(photo:true);
```